# How to convert a Dart Html client web socket response from Blob to Uint8List?

Tags: dart

I’ve implemented my own binary message protocol for simple request/response objects from a Dart client to a Java server. These are encoded in Dart as an Uint8List and on the remote server in Java as a ByteBuffer. The round trip works for the WebSocket in [dart:io] because the websocket.listen stream handler in the Dart client command app is passed data typed as Uint8List.

In [dart:html] the response data in MessageEvent.data received from the websocket.onMessage stream is typed as Blob. I’m not finding a way to convert the Blob to Uint8List. Because the response will often be a large binary array of numbers (double) that will be supplying data to a virtual scrolling context, I want to minimize copying.  Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), you need to use a FileReader to do this.

This example seems to work, the result type is a Uint8List when I tested this in Chrome.

```dart
  var blob = new Blob(['abc']);  
  var r = new FileReader();
  r.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  r.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
    var data = r.result;
    print(data.runtimeType);
  });
```

Another option is to set [WebSocket.binaryType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) to "arraybuffer". Then MessageEvent.data will return a ByteBuffer which can be turned into a Uint8List. See the example below.

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {      

  var ws = new WebSocket('...')..binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

  ws.onMessage.listen((MessageEvent e) {
    ByteBuffer buf = e.data;
    var data = buf.asUint8List();
    // ...
  });
}
```

Comment: @ Lowe I want to avoid a FileReader (copying buffers). I'm using websockets to support low-latency transfers of data with visualization components.

Comment: You can also set WebSocket.binaryType to "arraybuffer". Will update answer.

Comment: @ Lowe: Thanks. To make your answer complete, consider adding the following:     _onResponse(MessageEvent e) {
        Uint8List data = (e.data as ByteBuffer).asUint8List(); ...

Comment: @ DartTeam: There are a number of fragments in the documentation on web sockets, but they focus on the sending of messages to a server and don’t include a discussion of how to configure the websocket instance to receive binary data.

Comment: Glad it worked ;) I've added an example with the extra code. Much of the dart:html docs are autogenerated. Most of the code is also autogenerated from the blink IDL, so often checking on MDN is good enough if the docs are missing. Things are typically named the same.

Comment: this answer has saved my evening. finally i can go to sleep! Thank you!